# How to call ucf web service in node.js using SOAP

Tags: web-services, node.js, soap-client

I'm new to web service.How can i call ucf web service in node.js using SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, I think it will do what you need:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655534/1366519

Google and StackOverflow search boxes are useful if you type 'soap web services with node.js' or something like that.