# Creating a SOAP Webservice With node-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I followed this example of the git repo (https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap):

## Questions 1

I already created a server Is it necessary to create the server in the callback. From my understanding `readFileSync` is anyways blocking.

## Question 2

Wouldn't it be better to write non blocking and put soap.listen into the callback

## Question 3

Where do I get: `'myservice.wsdl'`. Do I have to create it/ How to create it? Is there a generator?

### soap.service.coffee

```
 exports.getService = () ->
  myService = {
    MyService: {
      MyPort: {

        # This is how to define an asynchronous function.
        MyAsyncFunction: (args, callback) ->
          # do some work
          callback({
            name: args.name
          })
      }
    }
  }

exports.getXml = () ->
  require('fs').readFileSync('myservice.wsdl', 'utf8', ()->
    server = http.createServer((request,response) ->
      response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url)
    )
  )
```

### server.coffee

```
...

http = require('http')
portHTTP = process.env.PORT || 61361
io = require('socket.io')
soap = require('soap')
soapService = require('./backend/soap/soap.service.js')

...

server = http.createServer(app).listen(portHTTP, () ->
  logger.info("Unsecure Express server listening on port #{portHTTP} environment: #{environment}")
)
soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', soapService.getService, soapService.getXml)
```

Comment: I made a sample for getting started. https://github.com/mrdulin/nodejs-soap/tree/master/src/get-started

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 1:  `readFileSync` is used to load the wsdl not to create the server.  So it is not necessary to create server in callback.

Answer to question 2: soap.listen is listening for a request and then that is processed.  It is the `# do some work` step that could be blocking hence the callback after that step.

Answer to question 3: You have to either create your wsdl when writing your SOAP API server or if you are using an existing service it should be provided for use in the form of a url ending in `wsdl`.

The `wsdl` is in `xml` and so could be generated.  [See which wsdl style to use notes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-whichwsdl/).

Also see my soap example project [nodejs_mock_agresso](https://github.com/ezzye/nodejs_mock_agresso).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your repo, was really useful to me. Only one thing? I was able to connect through the SOAP client using your examples, but I would also like to expose services via HTTP. Any idea on how to do that?

I see that in your files (for eg. globalweather.wsdl) you have bindings for Http (both get and post), but I can't access the services via http.

I tried adding the GlobalWeatherHttpGet and GlobalWeatherHttpPost ojects in the app.js, where you define the soap server, but it did not work.