# Consuming Magento SOAP API with Node JS

Tags: node.js, web-services, magento, soap

I'm using SOAP npm to try to get all the customer, but right now I'm getting **undefined** in the User List console log

var soap = require('soap');

soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {

```
    client.login(args, function (err, session, client) {
        console.log(session);

        session = session.result;
        client.customerCustomerList(session , function (err, list){
          if(!err){
            console.log(client);
            console.log('User List', list);
          }else{
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a reliable soap module for node.js yet. After spending some time trying to debug or modify the popular ones on npm, I took the advice offered in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22897376. It has worked well for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was missing some required parameters.