# Php Soap Client equivalent in NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, express, soap, soap-client

I am trying to replicate PHP Soap Client in NodeJS.

In PHP:

```
$result = $client->__SoapCall('PAYMENT_METHOD', array($params));
```

This is working fine

When I use node-soap and do the following in NodeJS

```
client.PAYMENT_METHOD([params], function(err, result) { 
  console.log(err); 
},{},header);
```

I get this error:

> <faultstring>Procedure 'PAYMENT_METHOD' not present</faultstring>

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: by the way I'm a bit surprised by the last arguments of your PAYMENT_METHOD. Are you sure they are {} and header?

Comment: any solution for this ?