# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3030

Tags: node.js, express, soap

I am using node.js, express js and soap (npm install soap).

I have created the code by following the below url:-

[Node.js: how to consume SOAP XML web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655252/node-js-how-to-consume-soap-xml-web-service/28639197)

but when i try to run it gives error like -

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3030
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3030 }
```

Comment: Are you running anything on port 3030?

Comment: Can you post a stretch of your code here?