# Test UI against REST/SOAP Services using testCafe

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, bdd, ui-automation, testcafe

I am experimenting with the testCafe tool and see if it would be a good fit for my web Application. I have an angular application and we are using JAVA + Selenium with a layer of BDD as our Test Automation Framework. Some of our tests require us to test customer account values in the UI for which we make a REST/ SOAP call to the underlying service and validate the values against the UI.

I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction as to how can I go about accomplishing this using a testCafe framework?

I have made some basic UI - testcafe tests that utilize the page object pattern and exercise some basic assertions but I am not sure how I can make a HTTP call and tie it back to my fixture or page object files.

I have gone through the test questions on SO and testCafe site but did not find any example that would help me with a start.

Any thoughts around this could be helpful to get me started at this point I am not really sure where to start from?

I apologize, I don't have any code sample for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using JAVA + Selenium, moving to TestCafe is just a matter to port your JAVA code to NodeJS by using either JavaScript or TypeScript language. Once done, you just have to import this nodeJS code inside your TestCafe test files.

Maybe you could start with this thread: [Node.js: how to consume SOAP XML web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655252/node-js-how-to-consume-soap-xml-web-service)

For the BDD part you could search on GitHub for [TestCafe and BDD](https://github.com/search?q=TestCafe+BDD)

Comment: thanks for the inputs. I will look through the info in your post(s) and come back with specific questions if any