# how to create soap php in javascriot

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, soap

I have this code in php for call data from public fingerprint with IP dan commkey number, and that is works.
my code look like this,

```
public function getdata(){
    $IP= "";
    $Key= "";
    if($IP!=""){
    $Connect = fsockopen($IP, "80", $errno, $errstr, 1);
        if($Connect){
            $soap_request="<GetAttLog><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">".$Key."</ArgComKey><Arg><PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">All</PIN></Arg></GetAttLog>";
            $newLine="\r\n";
            fputs($Connect, "POST /iWsService HTTP/1.0".$newLine);
            fputs($Connect, "Content-Type: text/xml".$newLine);
            fputs($Connect, "Content-Length: ".strlen($soap_request).$newLine.$newLine);
            fputs($Connect, $soap_request.$newLine);
            $buffer="";
            while($Response=fgets($Connect, 1024)){
                $buffer=$buffer.$Response;
                // var_dump($buffer);
            }
            $buffer = Parse_Data($buffer,"<GetAttLogResponse>","</GetAttLogResponse>");
            $buffer = explode("\r\n",$buffer);
            $result = []; 
            for($a=1;$a<count($buffer);$a++){
                $data = Parse_Data($buffer[$a],"<Row>","</Row>");
                $PIN = Parse_Data($data,"<PIN>","</PIN>");
                $DateTime = Parse_Data($data,"<DateTime>","</DateTime>");
                $Verified = Parse_Data($data,"<Verified>","</Verified>");
                $Status = Parse_Data($data,"<Status>","</Status>");
                $ins = array(
                        "pin"       =>  $PIN,
                        "date_time" =>  $DateTime,
                        "ver"       =>  $Verified,
                        "status"    =>  $Status
                        );
                $result[$a] = $ins;
            }
            return $result;
        }
    } 
}
```

I wanna migrate from php to nodejs with expressjs framework, anybody know how to convert that SOAP code to javascript?

I'm trying with this code:

```
var net = require('net');

var socket = new net.Socket();
  socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('server now connect')
});
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('data from server:' + data);
});

socket.connect(80, '45.61.163.12');
```

thank you for your care and response. appreciate it

Comment: Could you show what you tried and where you got stuck ?

Comment: that is working, i'm just wanna change the code (php) to javascript, because i wanna call the data in expressjs bro @TGrif

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655252/node-js-how-to-consume-soap-xml-web-service